# How to make react semantic UI TextArea with default value, but still allows user to change the value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, semantic-ui-react

I have tried using defaultValue and value in TextArea but it wont allow user to change the value.

The parent div of the textarea is redux-form Field. And try to pass the value stored in redux state to the textarea

```
     <Field
        name="message"
        component={renderField}
        ...
        onChange={ (e: any) => 
          triggerHoldResponse(e.target.value, conversation.id)
        }
      />

const renderField = ({input, type, meta: { error }}: any) => (
  <div>
    <TextArea 
      className={styles.textarea}
      {...input}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      type={type}
    />
    <div className={styles.errorSignal}>
      {error}
    </div> 
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

[SUI TextArea](https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/text-area#types-text-area) is base class for `Form.TextArea`, and both uses the same prop `value` for setting the default Text Value for the `textarea`.

Following Code works for me:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form, Input, TextArea, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const FormTextAreaExample = () => (
  <Form
    <Form.TextArea
      autoHeight
      onChange={this.handleMessageChange}
      label="Message"
      value={mesg}
      placeholder="Enter your request message"
      rows={3}
    />

  </Form>
)

export default FormTextAreaExample;
```

*Where `value={mesg}`, sets the default state of `textarea` (is set).*

Comment: This prevents me from changing the default value

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Semantic UI react you can use a Form.Field tag
You can set a default value and do what you are asking by using

**"defaultValue='default text you are trying to display'**

You can see a **Form.Field** Example below.

```
<Form>

<Form.Field
     name="description"
     required control={TextArea} 
     width={8} 
     onChange={this.handleChange} 
     label="Event Description" 
     defaultValue="Default text..." 
     type="text"  
     placeholder="Describe your event!"/>
</Form>
```

Note: defaultValue will override your placeholder and the defaultValue will not be removed when the click on textarea. 
If you want to just display info of what the textarea is for I would use placeholder.

Comment: Nice answer! Given current Semantic UI React TextArea doesn't have defaultValue prop

Answer (score 0):

You can link the value of the `Textarea` input to that of a value from `state` such that you can set the default text for the text but also allow for the state to be updated in turn updating the value. You can accomplish this using [linkstate](https://github.com/developit/linkstate).

Also if you already have the date in in your store you can set it up on the `ComponentDidMount` lifecycle event. to set the value of the `linked state value` therefore setting a default value.

Example usage from the docs:

```
import linkState from 'linkstate';

class Foo extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ''
  };
  render(props, state) {
    return (
      <input
        value={state.text}
        onInput={linkState(this, 'text')}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

https://github.com/developit/linkstate

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to use the textarea tag since I was not able to find proper solution

example:

```
<label className="wps-label">Message</label>
<textarea 
    name="message" 
    placeholder='Your message'
    onChange={(e)=> setMessage(e.target.value)}
>
    {message}
</textarea>

<Form.Checkbox 
    name='show_tooltip' 
    label='Show popup or tooltip when hovering over the spoiler' 
    value='yes' 
    onChange={onChange} 
    defaultChecked={data?.show_tooltip}
/>
```

or via react-final-form

```
<Form
initialValues={{ 
  title: modalView === 'add' ? '' : data?.title?.rendered, 
  content: modalView === 'add' ? '' : data?.content?.rendered
}}
```

...